# How to Edit input type text field created from servlet

Tags: java, jquery, html, jakarta-ee, servlets

I have created a text field from servlet

```
out.println("<input type='text' class='userValue' />");
```

it shows properly in my page. but when i click on the field it does not allow me to type anything.
I mean normally u see a bar blinking when u type. This blinking is not showing.

It behaves like un-editable text field (I am using jQuery ajax call to put this from servlet to my page)

How to resolve this?

complete code

```
protected void processRequest(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
            throws ServletException, IOException {

        response.setContentType("text/html;charset=UTF-8");

        String noOfNodeSt = request.getParameter("numberOfNodes");
        String action = request.getParameter("action");

        PrintWriter out = response.getWriter();
        try {

            if (action.compareTo("actionOnSelectedNode") == 0) {
                int numOfSelectedNodeReceived = Integer.parseInt(request.getParameter("numberOfNodes").toString());

                for (int i = 0; i < numOfSelectedNodeReceived; i++) {
                    out.println("<select class='nodeFromDB"+i+"'>");
                    out.println("<option>Servlet Action1</option>");
                    out.println("<option>Servlet Action2</option>");
                    out.println("</select>");
                    out.println("<input type=\"text\" name=\"userValue\" />");

                }    
            }
        } finally {
            out.close();
        }
    }
```

JS Code

```
$(function() {

    $('#nodeType').bind('change', function(ev) {

        var value = $(this).val();
        if (value === 'Single Node') {
            //alert("g");
            document.getElementById("spanSetNoOfNodes").innerHTML = "<input type='text' value='1' class='textBoxNoOfNode' readonly/><input type='button' value='Generate' onclick='tfc();' class='generateButtonAction' id='generateButtonAction'/>";

        } else if (value === 'Multiple Nodes') {
            //alert("g");
            document.getElementById("spanSetNoOfNodes").innerHTML = "<input type='text' value='1' class='textBoxNoOfNode'/><input type='button' value='Generate' onclick='tfc();' class='generateButtonAction' id='generateButtonAction'/>";

        }

         $(document.body).on('click', 'input', function() {
         //alert($('.textBoxNoOfNode').val());
         $.ajax({
         url: 'http://localhost:8080/M08CDECUStructuralOptimiser/Interface1?action=actionOnSelectedNode',
         data: {numberOfNodes: $('.textBoxNoOfNode').val()},
         success: function(response) {
         //$('.upItemName').append(response);
         document.getElementById("test3").innerHTML = response;
         }
         });
         });




    });


});
```

Comment: Post your full servlet `do<Method>()` code.

Comment: Tried adding form tag still same problem

Comment: Are you using ajax to get the html from the servlet and put that somewhere inside some other html page? If so, can you show where within that html?

Comment: JS code added pleas check

Comment: complete code http://pastebin.com/A7BKDGQb

Comment: If you try adding the `<input...>` line directly in your html, does it accept input normally?

Comment: yes it does. u can see that i tried that in last few line of my jsp code

Comment: If i press and hold mouse button on the text field i can type. but when i release the button textfield goes blank. there is no code written for key binding

Comment: At this point I'm just trying everything. Change your servlet code to show a full html head body and try going to `/M08CDECUStructuralOptimiser/Interface1?action=actionOnSelectedNode` with your browser.

Comment: i get 404 if i try to go that link

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/30424/discussion-between-sotirios-delimanolis-and-lynas)

Answer (score 0):

It was probably replacing the response over and over

i added the onclick='tfc(); and moved the following part in it

```
     $(document.body).on('click', 'input', function() {
     //alert($('.textBoxNoOfNode').val());
     $.ajax({
     url: 'http://localhost:8080/M08CDECUStructuralOptimiser/Interface1?action=actionOnSelectedNode',
     data: {numberOfNodes: $('.textBoxNoOfNode').val()},
     success: function(response) {
     //$('.upItemName').append(response);
     document.getElementById("test3").innerHTML = response;
     }
     });
     });
```

now its working fine